# How to select vml elements with jquery or pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, vml

I want to select an VML element with jquery without using 'id' or 'class' but my attempts didn't work.

```
<v:oval id="vmlElement" style='width:100pt;height:75pt' fillcolor="red"> </v:oval>


$(document).ready(function(){
    //don't work
    var oItem = $("v");//from here I should look for the n-th 'v' element, but for this example it is not necessary
    $(oItem).attr("fillcolor", "green")
    //alert($(oItem).attr("fillcolor"));

    //This worked, but I can't use select to id, or class
    $('#vmlElement').eq(0).attr("fillcolor", "green");
});
```

I know that `VML` it's too old, and is better to use `SVG` . But since we need compatibility with older browsers, we have to use `VML`. For all `Normal - Browser` We're using SVG and everything run like a charm.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by using the complete tag name which is `v:oval`.

Using jQuery:

```
$("v\\:oval")
```

Using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("v:oval")
```

Notice you need to escape the `:`.